# FluentValidation Rule dependency validation based on drop-down selection in MVC4

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, fluentvalidation

I need to validate two textboxes based on dropdownselect. It is dependency validation. for this I am using FluentValidation. Key thing is here, values of dropdownlist is language specification. (Russia, spanish).

```
RuleFor(x => x.HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereText).NotEmpty().WithMessage(i18n_Models_Abstract.RequiredField);
RuleFor(x => x.DtPublishedTimeText).NotEmpty().When(x => x.HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereText == i18n_Models_Abstract.AbstractYes).WithMessage(i18n_Models_Abstract.RequiredField);
RuleFor(x => x.PublishedPlaceText).NotEmpty().When(x => x.HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereText == i18n_Models_Abstract.AbstractYes).WithMessage(i18n_Models_Abstract.RequiredField);
```

### view

```
 <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 10px">
  <div class="col-md-10">
   <div class="col-md-4">
      @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereOptions)
      @{
           options = Model.HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereOptions;
           optionsList = options.Split(',').ToList();
           optionSelect = optionsList.Select(option => new SelectListItem() { Text = option, Value = option }).ToList();
        }
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereText, optionSelect, i18n_Models_Abstract.SelectOption +"...", new { @class = "input-validation-error form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereText)
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 10px">
   <div class="col-md-10">
     <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DtPublishedTimeText, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = Model.DtPublishedTimeLabel, maxlength = 40 })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DtPublishedTimeText)
      </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 10px">
  <div class="col-md-10">
     <div class="col-md-4">
         @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PublishedPlaceText, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = Model.PublishedPlaceLabel, maxlength = 40 })
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PublishedPlaceText)
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

### HTML

```
  <div class="col-md-4">
       <input id="HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereOptions" name="HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereOptions" type="hidden" value="да/yes,нет/no">
       <select class="input-validation-error form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="обязательное поле" id="HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereText" name="HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereText">
    <option value="">Выбрать опции...</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="да/yes">да/yes</option>
    <option value="нет/no">нет/no</option>
</select>
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereText" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <input class="form-control" id="DtPublishedTimeText" maxlength="40" name="DtPublishedTimeText" placeholder="Если Да, укажите дату публикации/If yes, Date" type="text" value="">
     <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="DtPublishedTimeText" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
   </div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <input class="form-control" id="PublishedPlaceText" maxlength="40" name="PublishedPlaceText" placeholder="" type="text" value="">
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="PublishedPlaceText" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
  </div>
```

[image]

All other validation are working, except this dependency one not working? Anything doing wrong?

Comment: Just a thing : why are option's `value` language specific ? I understand that option's `text` is language specific, but values could be neutral (numeric), no ? By the way, did you try to debug, and see what's in HasMaterialPublishedElseWhereText ?

Answer (score 0):

Dependent validation doesn't generate appropriate html attributes, because dependency value (true or false) would be known only after user input.

Neither **jquery.validate** framework (on which client-side validation based), nor **MVC model metadata infrastructure** (which used for simple rules that could be converted to client-side rules), doesn't support more than one attributes set, so, MVC infrastructure makes decision to generate no attributes at all.

Same logic works for **RuleSets** customization: rules defined under specified ruleset doesn't participate in validation attributes generation.